# Count unique elements from JSON array taking 2 different Keys into consideration - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have the following JSON array, which contains all the available metrics and dimensions from the Google Analytics API v3:

http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate/d22dcc

I want to make a table which includes the number of dimensions and the number of metrics. I can get this information with the following code:

```
var results = new Array();
for (var j = 0; j < output.items.length; j++) {
    var key = output.items[j].attributes.type.toString(); // make it an associative array 
    if (!results[key]) { 
        results[key]=1 
    } else { 
        results[key]=results[key] + 1; 
    } 
}
```

The result is: `[DIMENSION: 244, METRIC: 206]`

However, I would like to also obtain information of how many of these dimensions and metrics are public, deprecated or any other status that Google may give them in the future.

I assume there is a way to combine this information (type + status) in a single loop and array, but I am trying to obtain the status of the dimensions with the following code:

```
var statusDimensions = new Array();
for (var j=0; j<output.items.length; j++) {
    var key = output.items[j].attributes.type.toString(); // make it an associative array
    var subKey = output.items[j].attributes.status.toString(); // make it an associative array
    if (key != "METRIC" && !statusDimensions[subKey]) {
        statusDimensions[subKey] = 1
    } else {
        statusDimensions[subKey] = statusDimensions[subKey] + 1;
    }
}
```

However, the result is: `[PUBLIC: 414, DEPRECATED: 36]`, which denotes that the evaluation of the if condition `key != "METRIC"` is not doing what I am expecting.

1. Why is this happening? I can't determine the cause
2. How could I obtain an Array which include both information (type + status) in an unique loop?

Comment: Why do you think  if condition key != "METRIC" is not been considered.?

Comment: If you want both information, maybe you should create a 2-dimensional associative array.

Comment: @void maybe "not been considered" isn't the best argumentation, because it denotes that I am sure that the code is right, which I am not. I edited the question

Comment: @Barmar I will take a look to 2-dimensional associative arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it well, you want to ignore the items whose type is "METRIC".

With your code, in case it is "METRIC", the `else` clause is evaluated, thus incrementing the counter.

Instead, you can use something like

```
var statusDimensions = {};
for (var j=0; j<output.items.length; ++j) {
  var type = output.items[j].attributes.type,
      status = output.items[j].attributes.status;
  if (type != "METRIC") {
    statusDimensions[status] = (statusDimensions[status] || 0) + 1;
  }
}
```

Also note I used an object `{}` instead of an array `[]`. Using arrays when the keys are not positive integers is a bad practice.